# International formatting for directional angles?

Tags: iphone, ios, formatting, number-formatting

I'd like to present my users with an angles 20° and possibly a compass heading such as N or NW. Is there an internationalized number formatter in the iOS that handles angles? I've looked into NSNumberFormatter, but it seems to be oriented toward currencies and thousands separators.

Does anyone know where I can find a library that has them? I'd rather not have to do them all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you download the cocos2d framework, that has angles that you can use
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Comment: I followed your link looked at the online documentation, but didn't find anything about number formatting. Can you point me to an example? Does it include internationalization?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean, but here's an example of what I'm talking about:   CGPoint vector = ccp(firstPoint, secondPoint);  CGFloat angle = ccpToAngle(vector);    sorry if this isn't legible, I'm a little new to stack overflow and I don't know if there is any formatting for putting code in

Comment: Ah, now I see. That's actually basic trig- the angle between two vectors that start at the origin (0,0) and go the the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). What I need is more like an internationalized compass rose so that I have the correct internationalization for 20° W. I know that's 20° O in French, but I don't want to have to put in internationalized strings for each letter combination.

Comment: Oohh... Well sorry I have no clue how to do that :( sorry.